# Webpack config not compressing all css libraries

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, webpack-style-loader

Looking at my react application I am using ant design, normalize and some other CSS libraries to easily create components and use predefined styles. But for some reason, my webpack config does not compress these correctly into one main CSS file. But instead adds all the styles between `<head></head>`. http://take.ms/7a4o2

My webpack can be found here:
gist.github.com/martinsoender/dd978c9defc298889454b0035e2389cb

Comment: What does your webpack config look like?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your configuration, many configurations use the style-loader[1] and css-loader[0].

The css-loader adds `.css` as a supported extension emitting files for output.  The style-loader injects into style elements.  Similarly, you may have a css-in-js or similar tooling.

Style-loader is often for development, while another merge/combine loader for text/css is used for production builds.  YMMV.

[0] https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader

[1] https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-loader

Comment: Thanks! I found that the issue came from the declaration of my style loader.

Answer (score 1):

To compress / minify your css use [optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/NMFR/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin).

In your config all styles are added in `<head>` because of [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader), by setting it as fallback inside `ExtractTextPlugin` a css file named `bundle.css` should be output correctly.

This config should works if you use Webpack 3 (I added two comments in the snippet below):

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'bootstrap-loader',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                localIdentName: '[path][name]--[local]'
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: { sourceMap: true }
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: { sourceMap: true }
            }
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: '"development"',
      },
      __DEVELOPMENT__: true
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
    new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({ // minify css
      cssProcessorOptions: { // enable css external source maps output, you must set devtool: 'source-map'
        map: {
          inline: false,
          annotation: true
        }
      }
    })
  ]
};
```